# How to undo pending changes with git?

Tags: git, version-control

I am new to git. I have extensive experience with centralized CVS like TFS and SourceGear Vault.

I am using git locally (no remotes). Today I have made a complete mess of my projects when trying to revert back all changes made since last commit.

My repository stores documentation, VS projects and some other dev artifacts. There are several thousand files in total.

How do I revert back to the last commit (*undo pending changes* speaking TFS) for entire repository with git? 
`git reset` and `git checkout` just messed my files so I have had to use my file-level backups.

By undoing changes I mean:

- revert files edited since last commit
- add files removed since last commit
- delete files added since last commit

Items listed in .gitignore files should not be affected.

Is it possible to do such a revert on the folder (+subfolders) level instead of repository level?

With Vault I can *label* a folder(+subfolders) and later on I can go back to that labeled state. Can this be done with git?

Yet another simple question – can I view deleted files in a folder and restore them as needed (from some older commits)? I have not managed to do this with `git state` or `git log`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I revert back to the last commit (undo pending changes speaking TFS) for entire repository with git?  git reset and git checkout just messed my files so I have had to use my file-level backups.

An alternative would be `git checkout`, see [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout): *git-checkout - Switch branches or **restore working tree files***. For example: `git checkout -- .` checks out all files from the current branch, hence restores their state.

> Is it possible to do such a revert on the folder (+subfolders) level instead of repository level?

Yes, `git checkout -- path/to/folder`.

> With Vault I can label a folder(+subfolders) and later on I can go back to that labeled state. Can this be done with git?

I only know of [tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) on a repository-basis. However, you can checkout a folder for that particular tag (or commit): `git checkout tags/v1.0.3 -- path` or `git checkout commit -- path`.

> can I view deleted files in a folder and restore them as needed (from some older commits)? I have not managed to do this with git state or git log.

For example, use `git log --name-status`. Say I deleted *README.md* in some commit, it will show as `D README.md`. Assume it was deleted in commit *abc123*, then *abc123~1* is the commit before that (where the *README.md* still existed). You then can use `git show abc123~1:README.md` to see the contents of that file in the commit before it was deleted. A simple way to restore it: `git show 5235de78d28a07d2459130e7e3041b7720563b5d~1:README.md > README.md`.

> can I view deleted files **in a folder** ...

`git log --name-status -- path/to/folder`

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Should do the trick. This command will reset all of your files to how they were in the last commit you made.

Comment: This is what I have done 1st. `git log` then `git reset --hard 2f34...` where 2f34... was from the last commit. It just restored some VERY old data for entire repo. I just was needing one folder.